# Is the emu bush(Eremophila) invasive in california?

Tags: invasive

I would like to plant an emu bush(Eremophila), but want to know if it is invasive. Is the emu bush invasive in California?

Comment: It may not be listed as invasive as no one has planted it.  What is there about this plant from Australia that no other plant native to California can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not per Cal-IPC. There is no source more reliable for CA, but you can always call CNPS or Cal-IPC directly.

I searched both the genus name and the common name and the database returned nothing. Here it is:

http://www.cal-ipc.org/paf/

In addition, UC Davis lists at least one subspecies/variety as a low-water plant:

http://publicgarden.ucdavis.edu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/35_low_water_plants1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Srihari Yamanoor answered your question perfectly, with excellent references. I too did some research and found nothing to indicate invasiveness with this plant.

I know you didn't ask, but just in case you haven't picked out your specific variety yet, here's some information that might help you decide which will work best in your yard.

The Emu bush is part of the [Eremophila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eremophila) family, which includes over 260 species. Though native to Australia, they're grown elsewhere, and, as obviously you've noticed since you're thinking of ordering one, California is included.

The smaller group popularly known as Emu bush are comprised mainly of between eight and ten varieties. Foliage, flower colors and growth habits vary greatly. Some are low-spreading and work well as groundcovers. Others are bushy, and still others grow as trees up to nine feet. They're easily controlled by pruning though, even heavy pruning if you only have a small space, or you can choose the variety that already meets your specifications. Some varieties in California start flowering in January, although most wait until March, and continue for a few months. One reason people choose them is because, even though colors and shapes vary, most have tubular flowers with sweet nectar inside, so they're known for attracting hummingbirds. It makes them a great choice for areas of the yard where other hummingbird-attracters don't grow well. They're also wind-resistant, which gives you more options in terms of placement. They're quite cold-hardy, most as low as 25°F, and a few even to 20°F or 15°F. Unless your area is much colder than that, they make an excellent perennial.

As for care, they're pretty easy, and quite similar among varieties. They need full sun, around 6-8 hours a day, and heavy, well-draining soil. They should be watered sparingly and not often.

For further information:

[Smart Planet Plants](http://www.smartplanetplants.com/mobile/plantlist/catalog.asp) has an excellent list of six varieties with detailed descriptions, specific traits, growth habits and care instructions.

[The Smarter Gardener](http://thesmartergardener.com/emu-bush-friend-of-the-desert/) is a post written by an Emu bush owner in Woodland Hills, CA.

[Arboretum Spotlight, Spotted Emu, "E. maculata Alba"](http://www.sacbee.com/entertainment/living/home-garden/article32641938.html) is an article about a bush at the UC Davis Arboretum.

[California Gardens](http://www.californiagardens.com/Plant_Pages/eremophila_glabra_kalgoorlie.htm) offers informational pages about a few varieties.

Comment: My pleasure. That's an interesting plant I hadn't heard of before and I enjoyed learning about it. I hope you get one or more and have fun growing it! Let us know how it works out!